# cocoa/CCGeometry.h file not found in cocos2d 3.9

Tags: c++, ios, ipad, cocos2d-x

When I am trying to **build** my old cocos 2.2.2 game into the cocos2d-x 3.9 version, am getting  `cocoa/CCGeometry.h`  file is not found.This file is already included in the class.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your problem a bit more? Header file is not found if you not specify include path in your build (i.e. in makefile or something equivalent) ....

Comment: its included, during build am getting error

Comment: I mean its included in build as well (for example, in g++ we use -I<path_to_header_file> flag to provide path of header file to compiler so that it can find it). Otherwise, please check if its actually present somewhere on your machine.

Comment: i am beginner, what you trying say i could't understand

Comment: OK. Please edit your question and mention how you are building your source code? What error you get while building? What compiler and OS you are using?

Comment: i am using mac os and  x code editor. file is already included in class.but when i am trying to build my game that time its showing cocoa/CCGeometry.h is not found. i did't write this file myself ,it is already there.

Answer (score 0):

Below link that might help you,

http://hiltmon.com/blog/2015/08/01/simple-c-plus-plus-from-makefiles-to-xcode-builds/

(Look for `Header Search Paths` keyword in this page). It will show you where in your xcode editor project settings you need to go for adding header search paths.

But please also understand the concept behind header search paths.
Basically, when you do a include in your code like below,

`#include "file.h"`

then during build, compiler must know from where to read `file.h` file. Suppose this file is kept on some path like `/home/anand/MyWork/files/file.h` - then compiler will not find it until you specify above path (i.e. /home/anand/MyWork/files/) in your xcode settings under header search path settings.